# Django supervisord and apscheduler

Tags: django, supervisord, apscheduler

In Django project, have a supervisord than start apscheduler

```
[program:apscheduler]
command=/home/user/Project/.venv/bin/python manage.py runapscheduler
```

In apscheduler I have one job:

```
# runapscheduler.py
import logging
import sys

from django.conf import settings
from django.core import management

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import DjangoJobStore
from django_apscheduler.models import DjangoJobExecution
from django_apscheduler import util

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def my_management_command():
    management.call_command('MyCommand')


# The `close_old_connections` decorator ensures that database connections, that have become unusable or are obsolete,
# are closed before and after our job has run.
@util.close_old_connections
def delete_old_job_executions(max_age=604_800):
    """
    This job deletes APScheduler job execution entries older than `max_age` from the database. It helps to prevent the
    database from filling up with old historical records that are no longer useful.

    :param max_age: The maximum length of time to retain historical job execution records. Defaults
                    to 7 days.
    """
    DjangoJobExecution.objects.delete_old_job_executions(max_age)


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Runs APScheduler."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        scheduler = BlockingScheduler(timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE)
        scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "default")

        scheduler.add_job(
            my_management_command,
            trigger=CronTrigger(hour="*", minute="*"),  # Every hour
            id="MyCommand",  # The `id` assigned to each job MUST be unique
            max_instances=1,
            replace_existing=True,
        )
        logger.info("Added hourly job 'my_management_command'.")


        scheduler.add_job(
            delete_old_job_executions,
            trigger=CronTrigger(
                day_of_week="mon", hour="00", minute="00"
            ),  # Midnight on Monday, before start of the next work week.
            id="delete_old_job_executions",
            max_instances=1,
            replace_existing=True,
        )
        logger.info(
            "Added weekly job: 'delete_old_job_executions'."
        )

        try:
            logger.info("Starting scheduler...")
            scheduler.start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logger.info("Stopping scheduler...")
            scheduler.shutdown()
            logger.info("Scheduler shut down successfully!")
```

In my management command "MyCommand", I open some tcp socket to other server.
If I run it outside of apscheduler, the socket are closed correctly once the management command is over.

When it is run with apscheduler socket never close until I restart the job.

Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: Have you tried executing it with a cron job?

Comment: Thank you but I don't want it in a cronjob

Comment: Is it a requirement of your project?

Comment: yes it is, I have to schedule job with apscheduler

Comment: Could you post the code of that `MyCommand`?

Comment: Not really, I mean, it's a fairly long and complex bunch of class and method. But basically, it connect to a lot of external api and gather json.

Comment: Just wondering because if I'm not wrong what you have here is the basic code for a scheduler according to the docs